# Netlify React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, netlify

Deployed my website on Netlify but I need help running my server.js file to be able to run the contact form that sends emails.

Is it possible to run two commands in the build in Netlify. When I host it locally I run node server.js and then the contact form works fine.

I am using React for the website.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply a repetition of information you've already provided in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is meaningless.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to your question :

> Is it possible to run two commands in the build in Netlify ?

by default, netlify supports single build command. but you can create a custom build script that runs multiple commands in sequence.
For example you can create a custom build script (e.g., build.sh ) like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build the React app
npm run build

# Start the Node.js server
node server.js
```

later update your netlify.toml file , For example, if you created a build.sh script ,

```
[build]
command = "bash build.sh"
```

However, keep in mind that the server you start with node server.js may not continue running after the build process completes, as Netlify only supports **hosting static files and serverless functions**.

If you need the server to run continuously,Netlify offers serverless functions that allow you to run server-side code in response to HTTP requests.

Here is how you can do it :

- In your project directory, create a folder named
  **netlify/functions**. you can move your **server.js** file inside this foder.

Add the following to your **netlify.toml** configuration file:

```
[[functions]]
name = "server"
path = "netlify/functions/server.js"
```

Netlify will automatically deploy the serverless function and make it accessible at the specified endpoint, e.g., /.netlify/functions/server.

you can explore more about serverless functions here : [Intro to Serverless Functions](https://www.netlify.com/blog/intro-to-serverless-functions/)